# R : Select first value from gradio

Tags: r, radio-group

I am experimenting with gWidgets in R and simply trying to open a new gwindow for different values of selected option in gradio. There are 3 options and the last two work fine. When I select the first option, the error displayed is as follows.

```
Error in tkobj$env : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have tried to include the choices as a list too, but the error remains. The rest of the code is as follows. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
library(gWidgets)
library(base)
options("guiToolkit"="tcltk")
win1<-gwindow("Welcome to OCCUR", visible = TRUE)
g0<-ggroup(container = win1)
g1 <- ggroup(container = win1)
g2 <-ggroup (container = win1)
l1<-glabel(text = "Please select one.",editable = FALSE, 
container = g0,toolkit = guiToolkit())

#radio buttons
radiob<- gradio(c("Customer Data", "Sales Analysis", 
"Market Basket   Analysis"), horizontal = FALSE, container = g1)

#exit ok buttons
b1<- gbutton("Let's go", container = g2 , handler = newwin)
newwin <- function(svalue){
   if(svalue(radiob)=="Customer Data"){
     win2<-gmenu("1 ", visible = TRUE)
}
   if(svalue(radiob)=="Sales Analysis"){
     win2<-gwindow("1", visible = TRUE)
}
else{
    win2<-gwindow(" 3", visible = TRUE)
}
}
b2<- gbutton("Exit", container=g2, handler = exit)
exit<-function(h,...){
   dispose(win1)
}
```

Comment: Can you try this with gWidgets2? If there is a bug it will be easier to fix. The same code should run with the newer package.

Comment: @jverzani I did try it with gWidgets2. Nothing but the buttons worked. The label and radio buttons weren't displayed at all.

Comment: A couple things: You can only add one child to a `gwindow`, so only `g0` is there. Instead, pack in one `ggroup` into `w` and add to that `g0` to `g2`. Second, you define you handlers for the buttons after the button, so you get an error. Move the `gbutton` definitions so they are after the handlers. (As well, the `gmenu` constructor give an error, as it isn't a standalone window, but rather must be attached to a window.)

Comment: @jverzani I set the `gwindow` glitch. Shifted the `gbutton` after the handlers. And I changed the `gmenu` to `gwindow` and that does the trick! Thank you!